# Unable to run 2 Spring MVC Maven hibernate web apps in same tomcat server

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, spring-mvc

I started working on a 2nd Spring MVC maven hibernate project and wanted to re-use an existing working project as it had a lot of similar code and made sense not to start completely from scratch.

So, i created a maven archetype from the existing working Spring MVC project which uses hibernate however i cannot get my new web app to work on the same tomcat server.

The app simply returns a 404 error and the logs show the following error
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: src\main\resources\database\hbm\bannerItem.hbm.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)

The existing app still works fine.

I've tried the following..

1. Ensuring the build path is correct and showing the resource folder
2. Removing and re-adding the resource folder
3. Removing the reference to bannerItem.hbm.xml - cleaning etc etc - weirdly enough the error is still reported !
4. Removing the new archetype created project and simply taking a copy of the existing project and renaming project attributes - just to rule out an issue with the archetype creation, however the original problem persists.
5. Clearing the maven repo and re-downloading all libs just in case of some corruption somehow - this makes no difference.
6. Removed web modules from server configuration and cleaned - countless times - still no difference
7. Running project in difference workspace, same workspace, different tomcat instances.

Really hit a brick wall now and could use some help.
One thing i will mention is that i recall having a similar issue way back and when i removed the maven repo libs and re-downloaded them from within eclipse, it seemed to remove the issue above but then for some reason, my project would run, however jsp's would not render. I got round that issue by creating a new jsp and pasting the old jsp code in to the the new jsp, which fixed the issue - absolutely no idea why this fixed the issue but it did - tried this for this problem but this doesn't work, in that it isn't replacing the root 'resource' problem.

Hope someone can help here...happy to attach any code needed

Thanks

The full stack trace / log output is too verbose to paste in here, so here is the first and last of the output

```
16:31:59,271 ERROR [localhost-startStop-1] (ContextLoader.java:319) - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'bannerPageController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.stevebarnacle.site.services.BannerItemService com.stevebarnacle.site.common.controller.BannerPageController.bannerItemService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'bannerItemServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.stevebarnacle.site.dao.BannerItemDao com.stevebarnacle.site.services.impl.BannerItemServiceImpl.bannerItemDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'bannerItemDaoImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.stevebarnacle.site.dao.impl.AbstractDaoImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [database/hibernate.cfg.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: src\main\resources\database\hbm\bannerItem.hbm.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1120)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:626)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:663)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1642)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.stevebarnacle.site.services.BannerItemService com.stevebarnacle.site.common.controller.BannerPageController.bannerItemService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'bannerItemServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.stevebarnacle.site.dao.BannerItemDao com.stevebarnacle.site.services.impl.BannerItemServiceImpl.bannerItemDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'bannerItemDaoImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.stevebarnacle.site.dao.impl.AbstractDaoImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [database/hibernate.cfg.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: src\main\resources\database\hbm\bannerItem.hbm.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285)
    ... 27 more
```

.......

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [database/hibernate.cfg.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: src\main\resources\database\hbm\bannerItem.hbm.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1486)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:891)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:834)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:749)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:486)
    ... 55 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: src\main\resources\database\hbm\bannerItem.hbm.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.core.io.UrlResource.getInputStream(UrlResource.java:125)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:297)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1483)
    ... 65 more
01-Feb-2014 16:31:59 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
```

@jb-nizet, thanks - here is the file content

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd">

    <bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
               <!--  <value>classpath*:database/database.properties</value> -->
                <value>classpath:database/database.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driver}" />
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.user}" />
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>

        <property name="mappingLocations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:database/hbm/bannerItem.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>classpath:database/hbm/fileMeta.hbm.xml</value> 

            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
       <!--  <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property> -->
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

**Mapping file**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.stevebarnacle.site.banner.BannerItem"
           table="bannerItem">
        <id name="bannerItemId" type="int">
            <column name="bannerItem_Id" />
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        <property name="bannerItemHyperTextLinkUrl" type="string">
            <column name="bannerItem_HyperTextLinkUrl" not-null="false" />
        </property>

        <property name="bannerItemHyperTextLinkText" type="string">
            <column name="bannerItem_HyperTextLinkText" not-null="false" />
        </property>

        <property name="bannerItemImageSourceUrl" type="string">
            <column name="bannerItemImageSourceUrl" not-null="false" />
        </property>

        <property name="bannerItemImageOverlayText" type="string">
            <column name="bannerItemImageOverlayText" not-null="false" />
        </property>

        <many-to-one name="imageFileMeta" column="IMAGEFILEMETA" class="com.stevebarnacle.site.file.ImageFileMeta" not-null="true" cascade="all" unique="false">
            <!-- <column name="imageFileMeta"  not-null="true" /> -->
        </many-to-one>

        <!-- <property name="createdOn" type="java.util.Date">
            <column name="createdOn" not-null="false" />
        </property> -->

    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: Your code somehow tries r-to read from a file src\main\resources\database\hbm\bannerItem.hbm.xml, as the error indicates, which makes no sense at all. At runtime, there is no src/main/resources folder. There is no folder at all in reality: config files should be loaded from the classpath, not using file IO. As usual, the stack trace would show where the error comes from.

Comment: Thanks for the reply ...

In my web.xml, i have the following

`code`
<context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml, classpath:/database/hibernate.cfg.xml, classpath:/spring/mysite-config.xml</param-value>
 </context-param>
`code`

Comment: There was a hint in my comment: "As usual, the stack trace would show where the error comes from.".

Comment: lol - sorry, just about to add the stack trace, just trying to add some context first, coming in next post

and in my src/main/resources/database 

snippet from hibernate.cfg.xml

<property name="mappingLocations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:database/hbm/bannerItem.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>classpath:database/hbm/fileMeta.hbm.xml</value> 
               
            </list>
        </property>

Comment: stack trace added...

Bear in mind though that the same code works in one of the web apps but not the other, so i'm sure the code and spring config etc is working, albeit not in the 'copied' project

Comment: *Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [database/hibernate.cfg.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: src\main\resources\database\hbm\bannerItem.hbm.xml* : so the problem is probably in database/hibernate.cfg.xml. What does it contain?

Comment: @jb-nizet....added file content into main post

Comment: What you posted doesn't look like a hibernate config file to me, but to a spring config file. What's the content of database/hibernate.cfg.xml?

Comment: That is the hibernate.cfg.xml file content - this points to individual mapping files, added one of the 2 mapping files to original post

Comment: Then they're probebly not in the classpath. Check that the WEB-INF/classes/database/hbm directory of your deployed war file contains bannerItem.hbm.xml. And please don't name hibernate.cfg.xml a file that is not a hibernate config file.

Comment: Yep - all the files are in the tomcat folder - same as for the working app - i can't help but think this is an issue with copying the project ?

Comment: Any more thoughts on this welcome please - still not fixed..

Comment: Thanks JB Nizet appreciate your help

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you have not mentioned file path correctly for

src\main\resources\database\hbm\bannerItem.hbm.xml

in the hibernate config file.

Comment: It is listed as a classpath reference.

Comment: I can see how that might look obvious, however as said previously, this is how i use it for the working, original project and using it this way works fine - just not in the duplicated project.

I think the reported error is a red-herring

Comment: UPDATE - going to mark this as the answer, as despite doing many cleans and checking the classpath, it actually wasn't correct and instead of output resources as part of the build to 'target/classes' eclipse was using a 'default output folder', which wasn't correct and actually the classes were not in the correct folder for runtime.

However my project was still not working and this link helped with the final fix. Hope this helps others as this plagued me for 2 solid pain staking weeks !

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/riotfamily/mg7faVddOrY/xhcATla9mxYJ